# vlcj shows a black screen with an audio sound

Tags: java, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

Basically, i dunno where my error is, as i am trying to embedd a vlcj player USING java, but when i run this file, it only shows a black screen with an audio sound instead of a video.

```
public class Play2 {

private MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory;
// Create a new media player instance for the run-time platform
private EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private JFrame frame;
private String url;
private Canvas canvas;


public Play2(String url) {
this.url = url;

//Creation a media player :
mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
canvas = new Canvas();
JPanel panel=new JPanel();
panel.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvas));
//CanvasVideoSurface videoSurface = mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvas);
//mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(videoSurface);

//Construction of the jframe :
frame = new JFrame("Demo with Canvas AWT");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocation(100, 100);
frame.setSize(700, 500);
frame.setVisible(true);

//Playing the video
mediaPlayer.playMedia(url);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libvlc", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC");

final String url = "C:\\Users\\goldAnthony\\Videos\\Whistle.mp4";

new Canvas_Demo(url);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your frame has no content, you never added anything to it.

You need to add your panel to the frame.

There are a number of ways to do this, in this case it's simplest to do:

```
frame.setContentPane(panel);
```

You should also look at using vlcj's EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent, it's much easier (less lines of code) to set up.